# How do I manipulate these two lists (one a list of integers, one a list of pairs in list form) into a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

So I've done the legwork to build these two lists

```
print("Set of k values: ", kVals)
print("Set of (i,l) pairs: ", pairSet)
```

That gives the following

```
Set of k values:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
Set of (i,l) pairs:  [(2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (1, 0), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (1, 2), (2, 0), (1, 0)]
```

I created a dictionary mapping k values to ordered pairs, and then ordered pairs to k values.  I see that I only get the last 6 entries for the second dictionary because otherwise I'd have multiple outputs for a single input

```
dictGivenk = dict(zip(kVals,pairSet))
dictGivenPair = dict(zip(pairSet,kVals))

print(dictGivenk)
print(dictGivenPair

{1: (2, 1), 2: (1, 1), 3: (2, 2), 4: (1, 2), 5: (2, 0), 6: (1, 0), 7: (2, 1), 8: (1, 1), 9: (2, 2), 10: (1, 2), 11: (2, 0), 12: (1, 0), 13: (2, 1), 14: (1, 1), 15: (2, 2), 16: (1, 2), 17: (2, 0), 18: (1, 0), 19: (2, 1), 20: (1, 1), 21: (2, 2), 22: (1, 2), 23: (2, 0), 24: (1, 0)}
{(2, 1): 19, (1, 1): 20, (2, 2): 21, (1, 2): 22, (2, 0): 23, (1, 0): 24}
```

My next plan is to try to create a dictionary such that I can input an ordered pair from pairSet, and output a list of k values that correspond to that particular ordered pair.  See above where the ordered pair (2,1) corresponds to k values [1, 7, 13, 19].

*Edited to indicate I have ordered pairs as tuples now instead of lists

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: "I know part of this is converting the pairSet, but I don't know if into tuples or something else." Converting lists into tuples to make them hashable as dict keys is generally fine. Is there any particular reason why you have not given it a try?

Comment: I'm trying now, I'm just new to all of this and I'm figuring it out as I go.  I am more concerned about being able to output multiple k values, because dictionaries seem to have a "single output for a given input" rule, and I want to be able to group the k values into a subset.

Comment: The general pattern is to use a `d = defaultdict(list)` as an accumulator, loop through the pairs and accumulate. The dupe is not an exact solution, but the basic idea is the same: for your use case it would be iterating with `for pair, k in zip(pairSet, kVals): d[pair].append(k)`. Let me know if you need more help.